# PHP SQL Condition on ORDER BY

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to display all records with field_featured = 1 to start at the top of my listing ... and all the others to display at RAND()

So...

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
```

If (field_featured = 1 then ORDER BY field_featured) OTHERWISE (ORDER BY RAND() )

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
ORDER BY (field_fieatured=1) DESC, RAND()
```

Comment: It's funny to me that answers to the easiest questions earn the most rep!

Comment: Just one quick nuance - this will put rows in which field_featured=1 at the bottom of the result set.  If you want them at the top you need (field_fieatured=1) DESC, RAND()

Comment: OK, I'm trying it but for some reason it's not working. SQL looks like this: $query = mysql_query("SELECT mytable1.id,  mytable1.featured, mytable1.active WHERE mytable1.active = 1 ORDER BY mytable1.featured=1, RAND() LIMIT $start, $per_page");